# How to run Tern on the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, tern

I'd like to experiment with the [Tern project](http://ternjs.net/), including [AngularJS extensions](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-tern-plugin) for it.  I'm trying to run Tern on the command line, but it just fails with something like this:

> module.js:340
>       throw err;
>             ^
>   Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\users\myuid\git\tern\bin\tern'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:902:3

I have a feeling there may be an issue with doing this from Cygwin.  To be more explicit, I put the "tern/bin" directory into my path and ran "tern" from a new shell.  I've updated the error info above, just changing my userid to "myuid".  That path of "C:\c\users..." looks funky.  Something isn't translating properly from a cygwin path to a Windows path.

And note that I use this same Node installation to run Karma-based javascript unit tests, both from the command line for interactive debugging, and from a Maven build script, all within a Cygwin shell.

Comment: This is what `node` spits out when you try to run it on a non-existent file. Are you sure the `bin/tern` file is where you are pointing at?

Comment: Hmm, I have a feeling this is some problem with using this with Cygwin.  I put the "tern/bin" directory into my path and ran "tern" from a new shell, so it obviously found the "tern" executable. I'm going to add an update.